# How can I select only rows with multiple hits for a specific column?

Tags: sql

I am not sure how to phrase this question so I'll give an example:

Suppose there is a table called `tagged` that has two columns: `tagger` and `taggee`. What would the SQL query look like to return the `taggee`(s) that are in multiple rows? That is to say, they have been tagged 2 or more times by any `tagger`.

I would like a 'generic' SQL query and not something that only works on a specific DBMS.

EDIT: Added "tagged 2 or more times by *any* tagger."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HAVING` can operate on the result of aggregate functions.  So if you have data like this:

```
Row    tagger  |  taggee
       --------+----------
1.     Joe     |  Cat
2.     Fred    |  Cat
3.     Denise  |  Dog
4.     Joe     |  Horse
5.     Denise  |  Horse
```

It sounds like you want **Cat**, **Horse**.

To get the taggee's that are in multiple rows, you would execute:

```
SELECT taggee, count(*) FROM tagged GROUP BY taggee HAVING count(*) > 1
```

That being said, when you say "select only rows with multiple hits for a specific column", which *row* do you want?  Do you want row **1** for Cat, or row **2**?

Comment: Grouping by taggee doensn't ensure that duplicates are for the same tagger.

Comment: Oh that's a good point about which row. I didn't take that into account since I don't want a specific row, only a list of taggees. This is perfect, thanks.

Comment: @OMG Ponies that's where I was confused.  I am still not quite sure what is being asked.  It says "tagged 2 or more times by *a* tagger" so I didn't interpret that as a requirement.

Comment: @OMG Ponies I didn't care if the taggee was for the same tagger, only that the taggee was tagged more than once.

Comment: @Renesis I changed it from "a tagger" to "any tagger" in the original question to clarify.

Comment: @styfle Sweet. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t1.taggee from tagged t1 inner join tagged t2 
        on t1.taggee = t2.taggee and t1.tagger != t2.tagger;
```

Will give you all the taggees who have been tagged by more than one tagger